# Formatting Strings in an AWT List

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

basically I would like to add formatted Strings into a Java AWT List.

```
chinese = chinese.format("%s%20s%20s%20s", "Word", "Pin Yin", "Classification", "Definition");
words.add(chinese);
```

I'd like it so any future words I add into the List will be aligned in the same way (ex all the characters start at the same position)"

I tried to add

```
chinese = chinese.format("%s%20s%20s%20s", "漂亮","piàoliang","adjective","beautiful, pretty");
        words.add(chinese);
```

but they don't appear aligned in the list.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `format` trick only works with unproportional fonts (like *Courier*). With unproportional Fonts you could play with tabs (`\t`).

But in your case you should replace the `List` with a table like widget and use one column for each value to have proper alignement.